# Converting of Chord diagram into Plotly object in R

Tags: r, plotly, chord-diagram

I am attempting to convert a Chord diagram into a Plotly object because I plan to use it in a Shiny application later. I have tried the steps explained below, but without any success. Can anybody help me figure out how to solve this problem and convert this plot into a Plotly object?

```
library(circlize)
library(sfo)
library(cowplot)
library(plotly)

random_values<-c(500:100)

random_sample<-sample(random_values,15)

col.pal = c(BMW = "red",
            Honda = "green",
            Nissan = "blue",
            Tesla = "grey",
            Toyota = "maroon",
            Phoenix = "grey",
            Tucson = "black",
            Sedona = "grey"
              )
ChordPlot <- matrix( 
                    random_sample,
                    nrow = 5,
          dimnames = list(c("BMW","Honda","Nissan","Tesla","Toyota"),
                          c("Phoenix","Tucson","Sedona")))

# Converting to object
 ChordPlot <- recordPlot()

# Converting to Plotly object                            
 ChordPlot <- ggplotly(ChordPlot)
```

And the end I received this error

```
Error in UseMethod("ggplotly", p) : 
  no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "recordedplot"
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem and produce plotly object ?

Comment: `recordPlot` captures whatever is in the plot pane--there's no code that *plots* anything here. What is captured is base R plotting information, not an object with the class `ggplot`, therefore `ggplotly()` will not work. There is no built-in chord diagram in Plotly so `ggplotly` will not help, regardless of what's 'under the hood'.  It's possible to make a chord diagram in Plotly, but it defeats the purpose of using a library like Plotly.  ...when you re-ask a question expecting a different answer, you should mention that previous question...